# How to map model together with multiple foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to display Patient with their respective DoctorNote, Album and PatientAllocation Table. How can i join them together using model.

```
Patient Table 
Primary key: patientID

PatientAllocation Table
Primary key: patientAllocationID
Foreign Key: patientID

DoctorNote Table
Foreign Key: patientID

Album Table
Foreign Key: AlbumID
```

How can i use model to join all of them together or is that not possible. Currently this is what i did for DoctorNote. Since DoctorNote table contains a foreign key patientID. Model will map and display the result.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/PatientListPage/DoctorNoteDetails_XML")]
    public IHttpActionResult DoctorNoteDetails_XML()
    {
            var DoctorNoteDetails = Ok(_context.DoctorNotes.Include(x => x.patientID).ToList().Select((Mapper.Map<DoctorNote, DoctorNoteDto>));
            return DoctorNoteDetails;
    }
```

Comment: You should learn how to define and use navigation properties. Joins are rarely used in EF.

Comment: From your scant description it's impossible to tell how the classes are related. Start by adding references and collections to your classes (like Patient.DoctorNotes?) and then show us what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Patient: IPatient
{
 public int patientId {get;set;}
 public IPatientAllocation PatientAllocations {get;set;}
 public IDoctorNote DoctorNotes {get;set;}
}

public class PatientAllocation: IPatientAllocation
{
  public int PatientAllocationId {get;set;}
  public IPatient Patients {get;set;}
}
public class DoctorNote: IDoctorNote
{
  public IPatient Patients {get;set;}
}
```